# Change Select to DIV

Tags: jquery, select

I have a snippet, that basically converts the select to a DIV.

See:
http://jsfiddle.net/mBUgc/21/

```
var selectName = jQuery('select').attr('name');

// add a hidden element with the same name as the select
var hidden = jQuery('<input type="hidden" name="' + selectName + '">');
hidden.val(jQuery('select').val());
hidden.insertAfter(jQuery('select'));

jQuery("select option").unwrap().each(function() {
    var btn = jQuery('<div class="btn">' + jQuery(this).text() + '</div>');
    if (jQuery(this).is(':checked')) btn.addClass('on');
    jQuery(this).replaceWith(btn);
});

jQuery(document).on('click', '.btn', function() {
    jQuery('.btn').removeClass('on');
    jQuery(this).addClass('on');
    jQuery('input[name="' + selectName + '"]').val(jQuery(this).text());
});
```

This works great, the only problem being it puts the text of the select option (on click) as the value, rather than the select value itself.

So, normal select is:

value="412|Returning Price">Returning Price (A$60.00)

After changing to this JS, it comes out as:

value="Returning Price (A$60.00)"

Any idea on how to rectify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could keep the `value` of each `<option>` in a `data-*` attribute and get that value when changing your hidden input:

When creating the `<div>`s, add a `data-value` attribute with the correct value:

```
$("select option").unwrap().each(function () {
    var btn = $('<div class="btn" data-value="' + $(this).val() + '">' + $(this).text() + '</div>');
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) btn.addClass('on');
    $(this).replaceWith(btn);
});
```

When one of your `<div>`s is selected, call on that `data-value` value:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function () {
    $('.btn').removeClass('on');
    $(this).addClass('on');
    $('input[name="' + selectName + '"]').val($(this).attr('data-value'));
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mBUgc/43/)